# Efficient way to replace incorrect words in Series of strings

Tags: python, nlp

I'm working with text data, that is handwritten, so it has lots of ortographic errors. I'm currently working with `pyspellchecker` to clean the data and I'm using the `correct()` method to find the most likely word when a word doesn't exist. My approach was to create a dictionary with all poorly written words as keys and the most likely word as value:

```
dic={}
for i in df.text:
    misspelled = spell.unknown(i.split())
    for word in misspelled:
        dic[word]=spell.correction(word)
```

Even though this is working, it is doing so very slowly. Thus, I wanted to know if there's a faster option to implement this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: How fast is "not slow"?  Also, do you have a sample that can be used to benchmark against?